# What kind of tea is this?

Tags: translation

I was gifted some Chinese tea, but I have no idea what kind it is. Can someone please help me with this?

[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3]

Comment: Is the gift tea leaves, or a tea pot in which any leaves can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red part says 福 fú in modern character and old character.

The top just says 茶 chá
The bottom says China Patent Vacuum Tea-leaf Can, with 茶 chá in the middle.

Must be tea from 福建省 fújiànshěng Fujian Province (aka Hujian) I presume.

Conveniently, 福 fú also means happiness, good fortune, luck.

You know you can just add more water when the teapot is empty, that is, use the same leaves more than on time?